# In JDeveloper, how do I specify which class's 'main' to use?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

When I first set up my JDev project, it used the main method from the first class I had created - so when I hit run, it would use that as the starting point.

I then imported my project onto another computer, including a dozen classes, and when I first hit 'run', JDeveloper asked me which 'main' to start from - but I clicked on the wrong one. At the time I just left it, but I now can't find out how to specify the other class as the correct 'starting point'.

Specifically, I want to do this from within JDeveloper so it works when I hit 'run' on the IDE, I don't want to specify it in the command window when running it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Jdeveloper run target as follow :

- Run > Choose active Run configuration > Manage Run configuration
- Edit Default run configuration > Browse > Choose your Default run target

[image]